# How do I fix "Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated" error in Parse::Yapp?

Tags: perl

The Parse::Yapp currently shiping on Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial) is slightly behind perl in that it uses unescaped '{'s in regular expressions. The error message indicates that it's in YappParse.yp which doesn't exist. In the interest of patching it locally until a new version of Parse::Yapp comes down the pipe, what template file is it in?

{yapp}

> Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\G{ <-- HERE / at YappParse.yp line 288.
>   Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\G%{ <-- HERE / at YappParse.yp line 315.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>[Parse::Yapp](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parse::Yapp) hasn't had a release since 2001. I wouldn't hold my breath. Since it's effectively unmaintained I'd recommend either moving whatever you're using off of it or taking over maintenance. Consider something like [Pegex](https://metacpan.org/release/Pegex) or [Regexp::Grammars](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Grammars) instead.</strike>

Fortunately this problem has been reported twice, both contain patches. See [rt.cpan.org 114776](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=114776) and [rt.cpan.org 10668](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=106685).

[Maintenance has been picked up and 1.20 appears to fix the problem](https://metacpan.org/release/Parse-Yapp).

Comment: [Parser Generation in Perl: an Overview and Available Tools](http://inforum.org.pt/INForum2010/papers/compiladores-e-linguagens-de-programacao/Paper083.pdf) 2010 indicates that Parse::Yapp still holds reasonable value. It doesn't cover Pegex but LALR parsers offer considerable advantage over PEG in both speed and formality. Has Parse::Yapp fallen into disrepair or did it just not require maintenance until now? Assuming (hoping for) the latter, what's the minimum work involved in releasing an update?

Comment: @ericP [Parse::Yapp is a candidate for adoption](http://neilb.org/adoption/), try that channel. [Its bug queue](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Parse-Yapp) is remarkably small for a module that hasn't had a release in 15 years.

Comment: It appears that WBRASWELL has adopted [Yapp](https://metacpan.org/release/Parse-Yapp) and released V1.20 on 14 June 2017. Yay!

Answer (score 1):

perldb's stack trace revealed (or implied that) the file is Parse/Yapp/Parse.pm. Here's a patch:

```
diff -u /usr/share/perl5/Parse/Yapp/Parse.pm{~,}
--- /usr/share/perl5/Parse/Yapp/Parse.pm~   2001-05-20 07:19:57.000000000 -0400
+++ /usr/share/perl5/Parse/Yapp/Parse.pm    2016-09-18 02:12:09.116799976 -0400
@@ -880,7 +880,7 @@
         return($1, [ $1, $lineno[0] ]);
     };

-        $$input=~/\G{/gc
+        $$input=~/\G\{/gc
     and do {
         my($level,$from,$code);

@@ -907,7 +907,7 @@
         and return('START',[ undef, $lineno[0] ]);
             $$input=~/\G%(expect)/gc
         and return('EXPECT',[ undef, $lineno[0] ]);
-            $$input=~/\G%{/gc
+            $$input=~/\G%\{/gc
         and do {
             my($code);
```

Hopefully this will save others some detective work.

Answer (score -1):

This also occurs if you are calling a `ksh` shell script (such as `print`) from a non-ksh shell (such as `bash`).